# Programming tools for exploring semantic relationships between words

Tags: software, lexicography

By relationships I mean things like "hypernym", "hyponym", "synonym", "antonym".

I'm not quite sure what type of tool I'm after; I just want to "easily explore".

I discovered WordNet and the `wn` tool in Linux that lets you list such things. A point and click interface would be kind of nice. I don't know if any of the online dictionaries provide this sort of interface.

Comment: One interesting tool for representing semantic relationships within a lexicon is Kirrkirr, which so far has been used with [Warlpiri](https://nlp.stanford.edu/kirrkirr/).

Comment: I was reading through the [paper for kirrkirr](https://nlp.stanford.edu/kirrkirr/doc/ach-allc2000-ver5-single.pdf). I think the [picture on page 4](https://nlp.stanford.edu/kirrkirr/doc/ach-allc2000-ver5-single.pdf#page=4) gives a nice overview. It looks to be java based application from 2001. One would need to create a word list in its XML format which might be an issue.